# Old Identity of Cauchy's

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, math-history

So I'm reading this old paper by Cauchy's from 1847, and at one point, he merely states without proof the following identity: let $n$ be an odd prime number, and let $\rho$ be an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. Then
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\rho^{k}) = n .$$
Due to the fact that Cauchy states it without proof and without reference to where proof can be found, I can only assume that it mustn't be *too* difficult. Nevertheless, I am unable to prove it on my own, and if it is a standard identity (and it certainly looks familiar), I have been unable to find it by googling it.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never seen that identity before! If you can just give me a reference to where I can find its proof in turn, you will have solved everything for me! :)

Comment: What troubles me about this is that if you put $x=1$ in there, then on the RHS, you will be dividing by zero.

Comment: @JeanMarie I believe the upper index in product of your first formula should be $n-1$ rather than $n$.

Comment: Consider the computation as done in a formal sense.

Comment: @StormyTeacup The first formula does not contain division by zero.

Comment: @user You are right. I must re-consider the indexation.

Comment: @JeanMarie Also in RHS it should be $x^{k-1}$, not $x^k$.

Comment: What does that mean, "consider the computation as done in a formal sense"? Can't you say that too in the old 1=2 proof?

Comment: @StormyTeacup The formula $(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=x^n-1$ is valid for **any** $x$.

Comment: Another explanation : let $x \to 1$ and use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: Okay, I had to think about it quite some, but in the end, I recognize that the user with the confusing username of @user is right on the money! Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Indeed, the $n^\mathrm{th}$ roots of unity, namely $z_k = \rho^k$, $k = 0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$, where $\rho = e^{2\pi i/n}$, are defined as the roots of the polynomial $z^n - 1$, which can be factorized as
$$
z^n - 1 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (z-z_k) = (z-1) \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (z-\rho^k)
$$
thanks to the said theorem, hence
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (z-\rho^k) = \frac{z^n-1}{z-1}
$$
and finally
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\rho^k) = n
$$
by evaluating the expression at $z = 1$ with the help of L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: $z^n - 1$ is **not** the [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) of order $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Corrected.